# How to redirect a page

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter. Can someone know anything about this?
I am trying to redirect a page using this code:

```
window.location.href = "<?php $this->output->set_header(refresh:1; url=login); ?>";
```

But it is not working.

This is the code in my controllers.

```
public function view_login(){
    $this->load->view('login');
}
```

This is the code in my routes.

```
$route['view_login'] = 'Controller/view_login';
```

Comment: You can use redirect(controller_name/function_name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable URL Helper and set base url on `config/config.php`
in your **Route** just use :

```
$route['view_login'] = 'view_login';
```

and for redirect url use :

```
<script>
window.location.href = "<?php base_url().'/view_login' ?>";
</script>
```

if u not use .htaccess to remove /index.php use this :

```
<script>
window.location.href = "<?php base_url().'index.php/view_login' ?>";
</script>
```

> **Note :** for more information about URL Helper Codeigniter please visit documentation : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

In your controller 
`$this->load->helper('url');`

and in your view you can use

`<script>
window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('view_login'); ?>";
</script>`